# CSS Issue: Vertical line is short after heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a simple issue in my `CSS` code I want to create a **Vertical line** `after` my heading using **bootstrap utilities** but I faced an issue.

**Here is a live example of my code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h3 class="position-relative d-inline-block fw-bold">
      My Title Here
      <hr style="height: 2px;" class="position-absolute top-50 start-100 translate-middle-y opacity-100 w-100 my-0 ms-4 bg-primary" />
    </h3>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Expected Result:**

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Oh, and that's not a **vertical** line

Answer (score 1):

Close `<h3>` before the `hr`, and add `display: inline-block;` to `hr`. Remove the top and bottom margin set at 0 (`my-0`), as well as `left: 100%;` (`start-100)`, and `translate-middle-y`. Your position absolute along with the `margin-left` and `w-100` is making the `hr` appear to overflow. You can easily fix this by using `w-75`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h3 class="position-relative d-inline-block fw-bold">My Title Here</h3>
      <hr style="height: 3px;" class="position-absolute opacity-100 w-75 ms-4 bg-primary d-inline-block">
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple flex will do what you need

```html
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
  <h3>
    My Title Here
  </h3>
  <hr style="height: 2px;flex: 1;margin-left: 8px;">
</div>
```